# Combining two sections page numbers in a document with more than two sections

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document with at least 5 sections.  I am using a page x of y pagination system.  I would like sections 1 & 2 to read pagination-wise as if they are 1 section, e.g., page x of y where x is the page number for the current number of the page in sections 1-2 and y is the total number of pages in sections 1-2, but where sections 3-z restart and are only page x of y for the current section.  I have been unsuccessful thus far in linking or using formulae (albeit, I am rather unsophisticated when it comes to formulae in MS Word).

[Edit: The "y" component is using the SectionPages field rather than the NumPages field.]

Answer (score 0):

### Y from NumPages will always be the total number of pages in the document.

To have one section continue page numbering from the one before it, use the Format Page Number Dialog and tell Word to continue from the previous section.

### [Edit: Response to additional information on using Section Pages]

Using the **Section Pages field** you can use the Format Page Numbers dialog in your second section you want combined and tell it to continue from previous section. That takes care of the "x" part.

For the "y" part with combined sections, **you cannot use the SectionPages field in a header or footer within the combined sections.**

For the "y" part, you will want a Page field on the last page of your each section in the combined part. That should be formatted as white text or the same color as the background. Bookmark that field. Presumed bookmark names are "SectionPage1" and "SectionPage2."

The "y" part should be a [calculation field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-formula-field-32d5c9de-3516-4ec3-80ed-d1fc2b5bc21d) { = SectionPage1 + SectionPage2 } The Page fields in the body of the two sections will need to be updated, then Print Preview to update those in your X of Y construction.

Here is my writing on [Pagination Fields in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination) and on [Page Numbers in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers). See also [Greg Maxey's page on Page Numbering](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html).

Comment: This is simply incorrect.  If you use SECTIONPAGES in the field, it will give you the total number of pages in the current section.  You can have "Page x of y" for any number of sections.  My question is how in a document with more than 2 sections, how can I have 2 of the consecutive sections read as one larger document, but maintain all the other sections individually?

Comment: You did not mention that you were using SectionPages. I have edited your question to include this information. I have edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is probably:

Put the following nested field codes in Section 1

```
{ SET s1pages { SECTIONPAGES } }
```

Put the following nested field codes in Section 2

```
{ SET s2pages { SECTIONPAGES } }
```

In section 2, set the header/footer to "Link to previous", do *not* restart numbering at 1, and use field coding like this:

```
Page { PAGE } of { =s1pages+s2pages }
```

You will need to update the two SET fields (e.g. each time the section 1/2 page counts change) and possibly the header/footer fields to get the correct numbers.

In section 3, do *not* "Link to previous". In section 3 and later, restart the page numbering at 1. You can use the field coding

```
Page { PAGE } of { SECTIONPAGES }
```

(*All* the{} have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can enter on Windows Desktop Word using ctrl-F9)